# Exact time for activities monitored by Microsoft band

Tags: microsoft-band

I want to know the exact times during the night when i was awake or was experiencing deep sleep.

The data that Microsoft exports in csv format is the summed up data while the one it the graph on the dash board is no time stamped.

Is there a way to get the exact times when i was awake from the Microsoft band?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get more raw data about sleep activities by pulling it from the Cloud API, though that's certainly not as convenient as the using the dashboard.

You can find samples and documentation about the (preview) API [here](http://developer.microsoftband.com/cloudAPI).